# How do I keep the variable BGCD defined in a similar way, but usable in an Arc method?

Tags: java, drawing, integer, compatibility, variable-assignment

I apologize about the viewing format. I haven't been able to figure out all the posting details quite yet. 
If you Have and recommendations in regards to the formating too, please don't hesitate to tell me.

I'm Drawing a background for a hangman game. I'm working exclusively with visuals.

Eclipse is telling I can only use int methods in the Arc method.

```
final int XMID = 400;
final int YMID = 300;

//small cirlce diameter
final int SMCD = 60;
final double BGCD = SMCD * 2.5;
                 // ^^^^^^^^^^ problem          

//wave base
g.fillRect(0, 480, 800, 20);

//first big circle (ARC)

g.fillArc(XMID-(SMCD/2) , 480-SMCD , BGCD, BGCD, 0, 130);
                      //  ^^^^^^^^ problem          
//first small circle
g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g.fillOval(XMID-(SMCD/2),480-SMCD , SMCD, SMCD);
             //  ^^^^^^ problem
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I need to enlarge the BGCD arc object by 2.5 so that it overlaps with another object properly. However when I use the BGCD variable in the drawArc method it does not draw it because its not a INT type.
How do I keep the variable BGCD defined in a similar way, but usable in an Arc method?
-thanks

Comment: Please edit that into your question (replace what you have at the start with it, it is not useful, and feel free to re-edit the code block). Also please explain why you think it's not working because of that, and whether `SMCD` is ever something else than 60 (because using a double is useless with that value and the factors you're setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to cast BGCD to an int, 
i.e. `(int)BGCD` because the drawing methods don't work with doubles or floats.

Feel free to post the actual error message next time, it help you get a quick response